# Dynamic query with pager not working with filter values

Tags: paging, theming

I have a dynamic table with a form and a pager.
Table and form filters work fine.

But the pager ALWAYS retrieves ALL the records.  It does not consider the "post" value of the form filter.

```
function modulename_people_search($form, &$form_state) {

    // BUILD FORM
    $form['filter'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      '#title' => t('Filtres')
    );

    $form['filter']['filter_mail'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email'),
      '#size' => 15,
    );
    $form['filter']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Filtrer'),
      '#submit' => array('modulename_people_search_submit'),
    );

    // BUILD HEADER ARRAY
    $header = array(
        array('data' => t('Nom'), 'field' => 'nom.field_profile_nom_value'), 
        array('data' => t('Prénom'), 'field' => 'prenom.field_profile_prenom_value'),
        array('data' => t('Email'), 'field' => 'u.mail'),
    );

    // BUILD QUERY
    $query = db_select('users', 'u')->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');

    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_profile_nom', 'nom', 'u.uid = nom.entity_id');
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_profile_prenom', 'prenom', 'u.uid = prenom.entity_id');

    $query->condition('u.uid', 0, '>');

    // GET CONDITIONAL FILTER VALUE
    if(isset($form_state['filters']['mail'])) {
      $query->condition('u.mail', '%' . db_like($form_state['filters']['mail']) . '%', 'LIKE');
      $exportMail = $form_state['filters']['mail'];
    }

    // FIELDS
    $query->fields('u', array('uid', 'mail', 'login', 'status'))
    ->fields('nom', array('field_profile_nom_value'))
    ->fields('prenom', array('field_profile_prenom_value'));

    // GET RESULTS
    $result = $query->limit(30)->orderByHeader($header)->execute();

    // BUILD DATA ARRAY
    $rows = array();
    foreach($result as $data){
        $rows[] = array(
                    $data->field_profile_nom_value, 
                    $data->field_profile_prenom_value, 
                    $data->mail, 
                );
    }

    // ASSEMBLE DATA IN TABLE
    $form['table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#empty' => t('Aucun résultat.')
    );

    // ADD PAGER
    $form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));
    return $form;
}


function modulename_people_search_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['filters']['mail'] = $form_state['values']['filter_mail'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Form is being called twice... that seems to be the problem.  Can someone help?

Comment: And for information, theme name and module name are different (Drupal seems to have problems when a module and a the active theme have the same name).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?